# Image of irreducible representation of degree 2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, quotient-group

I'm a little confused about step 3 of the proof of the main theorem (page 8) of the paper [Limit Points in the Range of the Commuting Probability Function on Finite Groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0760) by Peter Hegarty.

He considers a finite group $G$ and an irreducible representation $\varphi\colon G\to GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of degree 2 (he also assumes that $Z(G)\leq G^\prime$ but I don't think that this is relevant).

There is a quotient map $\pi\colon GL(2,\mathbb{C})\to PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$.
Set $K=\ker\varphi$ and $L=\ker(\pi\circ\varphi)$. Clearly $K\leq L$. He claims that $G/L\cong\text{im}(\pi\circ\varphi)$ cannot be cyclic. I believe that $G/K\cong\text{im}(\varphi)$ cannot be cyclic as otherwise $\varphi$ would not be irreducible. This doesn't explain why the smaller group $G/L$ cannot be cyclic.

> Why can't $G/L$ be cyclic?

Comment: It's possible that the proof of the main theorem is trivial in the case where $G/L$ is cyclic (which would explain why the case is omitted), but I don't see why.

Comment: If $G/L$ is cyclic then $G/K$ is abelian ($G/L$ is a quotient of $G/K$ by a central subgroup of $G/K$)

Comment: Another way to think about it: suppose $\operatorname{im}(\pi \circ \varphi)$ is cyclic, and let $g \in G$ be a generator. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, $\varphi(g)$ preserves some line $L \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$, and cyclicity then shows that $\varphi(h)(L) \subseteq L$ for all $h \in G$. Hence the original representation is reducible.